# Enabling UWF freespace passthrough doesn't use extra available disk space, still stops at 1024mb

Tags: uwf

I am trying to use UWF overlay and I have it set to write the overlay to the disk instead of memory. In the docs it says I can use freespace passthrough feature if the overlay is on disk. This is supposed to let me use the additional space that is available on the disk for the overlay. However, it still caps out at 1024mb. Am I misunderstanding how this feature works?

Comment: Have you [configured the maximum overlay size](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/uwfoverlay?source=recommendations) for example using `uwfmgr overlay set-size 2048`

Comment: I have not increased the size past the default 1024, however, I thought that was the point of the passthrough, to just use the remaining freespace despite the max overlay size.

Comment: So you have specifically enabled the freespace passthrough with `uwfmgr overlay set-passthrough on`?

Comment: Yes correct, that is the exact command I used.